# Pick up names and find an 'n' inside the list and create a new list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create a new list from a list of random names. I want to pick up these random names and create a new list that has the letter "n" inside the name.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
rand_names = [ 'john', 'shawn', 'steve' ]
names = [ name for name in rand_names  if 'n' in name]
print(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a filtering list-comprehension.

```
names = ['john', 'shawn', 'steve']
names_with_n = [name for name in names if 'n' in name]
```

Output:

```
>>> names_with_n
['john', 'shawn']
>>>
```